# Turn off mouse highlighting in org-agenda

Tags: org-agenda, mouse, highlighting

When I am viewing my `org-agenda`, whatever line I have the mouse point on is highlighted. Since I never act on these lines with the mouse, and since the line where point is is also highlighted, the extra highlighting is distracting and confusing.

**How can I disable highlighting the line under the mouse tip in `org-agenda` views?** I am sure it is an easy fix, but I can't figure out the name of the relevant variable to customize. Thank you!

Comment: Is it your goal to disable the functionality of being able to click on certain things like tags and deadlines to generate an org-agenda buffer at the touch of a mouse, or do you just want to turn off the highlighting and leave the functionality so that the mouse pointer still changes when hovering over clickable areas?

Comment: @lawlist Honestly, I never use the mouse in `org-agenda` views, and am not familiar with the mouse functionality in that mode. I would be fine with disabling any mouse-related functionality in `org-agenda` as long as the highlighting goes away (the highlighting from the mouse - I still want the line with point highlighted as it is now). In other words, just turning off mouse highlighting is fine, and disabling mouse functionality along with it is fine too, but I am not as concerned about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I removed the mouse face as a whole in the agenda:

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook
      (lambda () (remove-text-properties
         (point-min) (point-max) '(mouse-face t))))
```

Answer (score 4):

I realize you asked specifically about org-mode,
but this might be of interest to others reading this.

A general variable exists: `mouse-highlight`. 
Setting it to nil disables highlighting of clickable text in all modes, keeping intact the click function. 
It is [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mouse-References.html) in the emacs manual.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to keep the mouse face (so that the mouse cursor still changes to a "hand") but disable highlighting:

```
(defun rg/modify-mouse-face ()
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (< (point) (point-max))
      (when (get-text-property (point) 'mouse-face)
        (remove-text-properties (point) (+ 1 (point)) '(mouse-face t))
        (add-text-properties (point) (+ 1 (point)) (list 'mouse-face (face-at-point t))))
      (forward-char))))
(add-hook 'org-finalize-agenda-hook 'rg/modify-mouse-face t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @mutbuerger's answer, I ended up with this solution that I preferred:

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'mouse-highlight)
            (setq mouse-highlight nil)))
```